# Is there an AIX API to get stack trace?

Tags: c++, aix

I understand there is system call `mt__trce`, but I would like an API method to give the call stack information that I can use in a C++ program. Is there such a method?

Comment: mmm, is that Windows, Linux or Mac or what?

Comment: @ForceBru: tags (and subject) says AIX

Comment: @ForceBru: Neither. AIX is IBM's proprietary Unix operating system.

Comment: With xlc, using `mt__trce` to dump a core for later analysis appears to be all you can do.  If using glibc, you can use `backtrace()`.  Look at the more generic question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c ; several answers there give alternatives that may solve your problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight I´ve tried to do the same that you attempted and did not suceeded
 Have you found any way to dissect context->uc_mcontext.jmp_context aix structure to get PC and SP?
My searches send me to this answer (bottom) that seems to get a backtrace, but i cant find the arm_pc or the gregs[REG_PC] structure on AIX. I should use them to get PC and SP and them get functions. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559347/how-to-unwind-the-stack-to-get-backtrace-for-the-specified-stack-pointer-sp