# Where function name is stored in stack frame in ARM7l (Not function address in link register "lr")

Tags: c, linux, unix, arm

Can any body please tell me where function name is stored in stack frame . I know return address is stored in link register (lr) . But my requirement is to implement backtrace which print function name I don't want to print function address .

Comment: I'm pretty sure function name is never stored on stack.

Comment: [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer) gives details on how to do this manually; this is **NOT** a canned solution so it sounds like it is not for you.  You can also use `/proc/self/stack` if it exists to see kernel call stack for the task.  This depends on a kernel `.config` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve function name from function address using link register (like backtrace\_symbol) in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685976/how-to-retrieve-function-name-from-function-address-using-link-register-like-ba) and also [How to unwind...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559347/how-to-unwind-the-stack-to-get-backtrace-for-the-specified-stack-pointer-sp)

Answer (score 5):

There are two API `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` you can use to print  backtrace information. please use `man backtrace` for more details about these two APIs.

As for function name, I do not think it is saved in stack frame, you need refer to map information/symbol table to find it with address.

Comment: Yes I am doing on my x86 architecture it working with `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` but I want it for ARM architecture . inbuild library is not supporting that.

Comment: What do you mean by inbuild library?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya If you use binutil tools such as `readelf -a`, for ARM, it should be something like `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-readelf`, you will find function name are saved in .symtab section, with value, maybe it will give you some clue about how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ function name is not stored in stack frame.

Comment: Then how can I get function name using stack frame information like `backtrace_symbols()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Preprocessor symbols:
`__FILE__` and `__LINE__`
Somthing like:`printf("File: " __FILE__ "in Line: " __LINE__);`

This returns the current file and the line the function was called. Note that the string is stored in memory. So don't use this to often.